# How do you tell the difference between MariaDB and MySQL from a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Is there any way to detect whether it's MySQL being used or MariaDB being used?
As this would be useful in making MariaDB specific optimizations.

Comment: detect based on what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

This is from Maria DB

```
version=10.0.7-MariaDB-1~quantal-log
```

This is from MySQL

```
version_comment=MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

With PDO you can use `ATTR_SERVER_VERSION` attribute to get server version:

```
echo $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION); // output: <major>.<minor>.<build>-MariaDB
```